# How to convert canvas image to standard img?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I surfing inside StackOverflow and can't find proper solution.

I have serval canvas images what I want to convert in regular `<img>` tag to can send via email like normal HTML.

That canvas image is generaly caption from video. That part works well until I want to convert canvas to image.

here is example:

```
$(document).on('input change paste keyup','.add-video',$.debounce(350,function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('data-id'),
        type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        value = $(this).val().trim(),
        main = $('.editable-open').find('tr > td');

    if(value == '' && type != 'alt')
        value=null;

    if(type == 'src'){
        if($.isVideo(value))
        {

            var videoFormat = function(value){
                    var $get = value.split('.');
                    return 'video/' + $get[($get.length-1)];
                },
                video = '<video id="get-video-poster" src="' + value + '" type="' + videoFormat(value) + '" style="display:none"></video><canvas id="video-canvas"></canvas>';

            // 1) - Get video and generate canvas image
            main.html(init.tooltips + video).promise().done(function(){
                var canvas = $('#video-canvas').get(0),
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    video = $('#get-video-poster').get(0);

                $('#get-video-poster').on("loadeddata", function () {
                    context.drawImage(video, 5, 5, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
                    $(this).remove();

                    main.find('img').remove();

                    // 2) Get constructed canvas and made regular image
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        var can = document.getElementById('video-canvas');
                        var src = can.toDataURL("image/png", 1);
                        console.log(src);
                        main.append('<img src="'+src+'">');
                    },1000);

                });
            });

        }
        else
        {
            $.get(window.base + '/themes/form-video.html').done(function(html){
                main.html(init.tooltips + html);
            });
        }
    }
}));
```

From this code, stage 2 not work. I trying to get constructed canvas and made regular image.

In console I getting `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

@T.J. Crowder - Don't know do you read or understand this problem, but solution wat you mention is not helpfull because `toDataURL()` not give me URL. Look my code carefully.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - Don't know do you read or understand this problem, but solution wat you mention is not helpfull because toDataURL() not give me URL. Look my code carefully.

Comment: *"...because toDataURL() not give me URL..."* Er, it does. It's right there in the name! :-)

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić If you mean you don't get a URL returned from the call to `toDataURL()` then you are likely asking a different question. The choice is whether to edit the existing question or to ask a new question with the tighter focus on why you aren't getting a URL returned.  Have you looked into why your canvas might be tainted?